# Solving cosh/sinh equation

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

I struggle with equations involving exponentials... In particular, I don't find how to solve this one analytically. I found graphically that there is exactly one solution when $a \geq 1$ but I cannot solve that analytically...

Any help is greatly appreciated. The goal is to find for which value(s) of $a$ the following equations admits exactly one solution. Any help is greatly appreciated...

$$
x (\mathrm{exp}({\frac{2x}{a^2}}) + 1) = \mathrm{exp}({\frac{2x}{a^2}}) - 1
$$

Comment: Why do you think you can solve it algebraically ? Do you only need existence of a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Say $a\neq 0$.

$x=0$ is a solution. So you should make it to be the only one. The equation can be written, with $z=\frac{2x}{a^2}$, as $$\frac{a^2}{2}z=\tanh \frac z 2$$ Now note that $\frac{d}{dz}\tanh \frac z 2=\frac12\mbox{sech}^2 \frac{z}{2}\le\frac12$. On the other hand $\tanh \frac z 2 \leq1$ so if $\frac{a^2}2< \frac12$, then there will be three roots, otherwise you will have only one root which is $x=0$.